# Javascrip load is breaking the onclick of the loaded item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to refactor the menu navigation.
I want to add it into a single html file. example: menu.html will contain :

```
<div class="menu-toggle" id="menuToggle">
    <span></span>
</div>
other divs aswell
```

For each page I want to inject this html code. (to increase code reuse).
using
other html page:

```
<div id='menu=left'></div>
```

I have in the main.js:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    function menu() {
        "use strict";
        $("#menuToggle").on("click", function () {
            $(".header-left").toggleClass("open");
            $(".main").toggleClass("open");
        });
        $(".cross").on("click", function () {
            $(".header-left").removeClass("open"); 
        });
        $(".nav-link").on("click", function () {
            $(".header-left").removeClass("open");
        });
    }

    $(”#menu-left”).load(“assets/html/menu.html”);

    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        "use strict";
        menu();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

The output :

The menu appears. I can see the menu button but the toggle functionality does not work anymore.
I tried different things but can't seem to work it out.

How can I solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use delegated event handlers as you're adding the menu HTML dynamically after the page loads. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: Also note that while using `load()` does increase code reuse, it means more server requests being made, and potentially more hosting cost and worse server performance. I'd strongly suggest you use server side includes instead of client side ones.

Comment: You'll also get a FOUC as your page loads, displays, then there's a delay as the menu loads separately

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am not sure i understand what i have to do in order to fix this ? Am i supposed to add the content before the page loads ?